# Retrofit2 parsing error message Logcat

Tags: java, json, eclipse, retrofit2

i have a strange logcat message while creating app for Android .I'm calling a webservice and creating a listview in the process. I' m currently using retrofit2 for this.

```
public ArrayList<AgencyModel> DownloadAgencyData() {

        RestApi.getUnicsAgencyApi().getStreams().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<AgencyModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<AgencyModel>> arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("Error in parsing", arg0.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<AgencyModel>> AgencyModelData,
                    Response<ArrayList<AgencyModel>> response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mstreamData = new ArrayList<AgencyModel>();
                // ADD TO List here!!!!!!!!
                // Log.e("Response", "" + response.body().size());
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    mstreamData.addAll(response.body());
                }

            }

        });
        return mstreamData;
    }
```

The builder class is as follows:

```
public class RestApi {
    private static String ENDPOINT_URL = "http://192.168.1.102/UnicsApplication/";
    private static UnicsAgencyApi sUnicsAgencyApi;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static UnicsAgencyApi getUnicsAgencyApi() {

        if (sUnicsAgencyApi == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ENDPOINT_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            sUnicsAgencyApi = retrofit.create(UnicsAgencyApi.class);
        }
        return sUnicsAgencyApi;
    }

    public interface UnicsAgencyApi {

        //@GET("api/uconnectservice/AllAgency")
        @GET("api/uconnectservice")
        Call<ArrayList<AgencyModel>> getStreams();
    }

}
```

The Complete logcat message it get is as follows:

```
    01-03 16:55:54.592: W/ResourceType(2794): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 36 bytes
01-03 16:55:54.912: I/ActivityManager(2794): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41a364b0 time:190796801
01-03 16:56:06.152: D/LIST STATUS(2794): AgencyList is null
01-03 16:56:06.182: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
01-03 16:56:06.182: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
01-03 16:56:06.182: I/dalvikvm(2794): Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
01-03 16:56:06.182: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3073: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
01-03 16:56:06.182: D/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
01-03 16:56:06.192: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
01-03 16:56:06.192: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
01-03 16:56:06.192: I/dalvikvm(2794): Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
01-03 16:56:06.192: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3072: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
01-03 16:56:06.192: D/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
01-03 16:56:16.192: E/Error in parsing(2794): retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@41bdff80
```

I was hoping anybody could guide or explain why this is happening.
For clarity sake here is my JAVA model

```
package com.nickSoft.Models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AgencyModel {

    @SerializedName("AgencyName")
    @Expose
    private String agencyName;
    @SerializedName("AgencyLocation")
    @Expose
    private String agencyLocation;
    @SerializedName("AgencyPhoneNumber")
    @Expose
    private String agencyPhoneNumber;
    @SerializedName("AgencyGPSCoordinates")
    @Expose
    private String agencyGPSCoordinates;
    @SerializedName("AgencyHours")
    @Expose
    private String agencyHours;

    public String getAgencyName() {
        return agencyName;
    }

    public void setAgencyName(String agencyName) {
        this.agencyName = agencyName;
    }

    public String getAgencyLocation() {
        return agencyLocation;
    }

    public void setAgencyLocation(String agencyLocation) {
        this.agencyLocation = agencyLocation;
    }

    public String getAgencyPhoneNumber() {
        return agencyPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setAgencyPhoneNumber(String agencyPhoneNumber) {
        this.agencyPhoneNumber = agencyPhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAgencyGPSCoordinates() {
        return agencyGPSCoordinates;
    }

    public void setAgencyGPSCoordinates(String agencyGPSCoordinates) {
        this.agencyGPSCoordinates = agencyGPSCoordinates;
    }

    public String getAgencyHours() {
        return agencyHours;
    }

    public void setAgencyHours(String agencyHours) {
        this.agencyHours = agencyHours;
    }

}
```

and here is the JSON coming in from webservice:

```
[{"AgencyName":"Head-Office/Branch","AgencyLocation":"Immeuble Grand Carrefour Rue Marie Gocker,Yaounde","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222229610/691698762","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Yaounde-Marche-Centrale Branch","AgencyLocation":"Immeuble Grand Carrefour Rue Marie Gocker,Yaounde","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041661/22229604/91697426","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Bamenda Branch","AgencyLocation":"Evidence Building, City Chemist Roundabout,Bamenda","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041665/233364170/691697553","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Deido Branch","AgencyLocation":"Face Boulangerie COAF, Douala","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041660/633402641/691697494","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Bafut Branch","AgencyLocation":"Midland Centre, 3 Corners Njinteh, Bafut","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237675025263/691698716","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Buea Branch","AgencyLocation":"University Junction, Molyko, Buea","AgencyPhoneNumber":" +237222041664/333323322/691698625","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Bonaberi Branch","AgencyLocation":"Cimetière, Immeuble Pharmacie Bonaberi, Douala","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041663/333392710/691697617","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Biyem-Assi Branch","AgencyLocation":"Carrefour Biyem-assi ,Yaounde","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041662/222316710/691698667","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Limbe Branch","AgencyLocation":"Down Beach, Sappa Road, Limbe","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041690/222041693/691698628","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Kribi Branch","AgencyLocation":"Adjacent Auto Ecole Française Rue Petit Paris, Kribi","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041691/222041692/691698632","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Akwa Branch","AgencyLocation":"Boulevard de la Liberté, Douala","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041670/691698663","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Dakar Branch","AgencyLocation":"Marché Bilongué, Douala","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237691698627","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Bambili Branch","AgencyLocation":"Three Corners, Bambili","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222054199/691697441","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Tchinga Branch","AgencyLocation":"Ave du 27 Août 1940,Yaounde","AgencyPhoneNumber":"691907381","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"},{"AgencyName":"Kumba Branch","AgencyLocation":"Kumba","AgencyPhoneNumber":"+237222041664","AgencyGPSCoordinates":"GPS Position","AgencyHours":"8:00-16:00"}]
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you instead print the error message generated by the second argument instead?
As that would be more helpful.
`Log.e("Error in parsing", arg1.getMessage());`

Comment: @HarshitDwivedi i have just provided the logcat i recieve,So it appears  that a response is recieved (i.e. the onFailure() is never called)but is not being handled properly by Retrofit. Any suggestions?

Comment: But in the Logcat, onFailure *is* called, because the corresponding log message is shown in the logcat. `E/Error in parsing(2794):`

Comment: Ah i missed that, then what do you suggest pls?

Comment: Ok, first replace the line `Log.e("Error in parsing", arg0.toString());` in your onFailure with `Log.e("Error in parsing", arg1.getMessage());`.
Second, post the JSON response from the server that you are trying to parse and display.

Comment: ok @HarshitDwivedi i edited my question to show JSON response and java model class...so close but so far...

Comment: Ok, the POJO and the response looks fine, could you also link the Retrofit service Builder classes too?

Comment: Ok @HarshitDwivedi i have added it (see edit),grateful for your eyes and knowledge :)

Comment: Ok, everything looks good to me, just out of curiosity, have you added the internet permission in your manifest?
Also if you have, then add the HTTPLogging client to your retrofit builder and then post the logs from the terminal.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

Comment: Ok yes i have internet permission in my android manifest,will add HTTPLogging client right away and post logs ...so close but so far....

Comment: @HarshitDwivedi am i supposed to see anything in the Logcat after i paste the code for HTTPLogging client?

Comment: Yes you should. The logging should be in the debug tab and will should you the response code and the time taken to receive it. This will help us know if the data was received properly.